# Validating using Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to generate a Regular expression that will validate that there is a String having numbers separated by `“,”` and then after that there is String separated by `“|”` from these Numbers.
Ex: `12,14,15|It is an error`

This above example is a String wich contains numbers before the `'|'` which can have commas but not text and the text after the `'|'` cannot contain any comma. As of now I'm using `[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*` for numbers and `^[^,]*$` for text and use `,|\\|` for removing the `,` and `|` for further processing. But I need it all in one Regex.
Could anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*\|[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

This should do it.

or

```
^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*\|[^,]+$
```

Comment: When I give this, String regexp = "^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*\|[^,]+$";, It shows invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \ ) syntax error pattern. How can I fix it?

Comment: @user1311991 `^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*\\|[^,]+$`

Comment: Is there any way that I can split the error message as a separate string and error codes as separate string array and put it in a map,without using any other additional regex? Plz help!

Comment: ^([0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*)\\|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ . This Regex returns false for this input, 12,14,15|There is an error

Comment: ^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*\|[a-zA-Z0-9]+$. This one gave me invalid escape sequence so I added a '\'  ^([0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*)\\|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$. I guess adding '\' is giving problem. Any workaround?

Comment: @user1311991 in java you have to escape `\` by `\\`.Sry i forgot to tell you

Comment: so,is it right? ^([0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*)\\|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$... Am I giving'\' at the right place?

Comment: @user1311991 yes its correct :) `^([0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*)\\|([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)$`

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class test
{
    public static void main( String args[] ){

```
  // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
  String line = "12,14,15|It is an error";
  String pattern = "^[0-9]+([^|]+)";

  // Create a Pattern object
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  // Now create matcher object.
  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
  while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

}
}

Comment: But when checked whether "12,14,15|It is an error" is a valid string, it returns false. Shouldn't it be true? That is what I want to check.